# Can any kind of public-key encryption hold up against a logically omniscient oracle?

Tags: communication, computers

"Logical omniscience" can be defined for these purposes as a form of hypercomputation in which all Turing-computable functions can be computed in constant time. Practically speaking, this means that if you have all of the information that is logically necessary to solve a problem, you can effectively instantly know the answer to that problem.

Things like RSA are clearly out--they depend on certain theoretically-computable functions (like modular factorization) to be difficult to actually compute in practice, and fall apart under much weaker hypercomputation models. Other models, like elliptic-curve cryptography, are more robust than RSA, but still would fail against a logically omniscient oracle with infinite computing power.

Meanwhile, symmetric private key cryptography should still be mostly safe, because there is no algorithm to compute a single unique plaintext-key pair from a given ciphertext. An attacker could decide what they want the plaintext to be, and calculate what they key would've have to have been to get that, but that doesn't actually give you any information about what the original plaintext and key actually were. You can only build up statistical arguments if you have multiple messages that someone had the poor sense to encrypt with the same key, which is no different from how things work in the real world anyway.

So, are there any public-key encryption schemes that would be safe against a logically omniscient oracle? Where breaking them is not merely a matter of not having enough computational power, but for which a deterministic algorithm simply *doesn't exist*?

Background reason for the question: I have a world in which "demons" can be contacted to enact magic; one of their abilities, which is integral to the kind of magic they can perform, is hypercomputation, such that they can solve problems that are well beyond the *technological* abilities of the people summoning them (thus providing a justification for the risk of consorting with demons). However, making them *too* powerful may end up ruling out some magi-tech applications I want (like access to strong cryptography), so I'm trying to figure out what the maximum level of hypercomputation is that I can give to the demons without breaking the setting.

Comment: This question is well beyond my expertise, but by golly do hypercomputational demons sound awesome.

Comment: Secure public key cryptography is basically out if the adversary has effectively unlimited classical computing power. Realistically you would really need to be looking towards routine use of things like quantum key distribution involving keys at least the full length of the message to overcome this. It is of course still theoretically possible to attempt to guess the key by brute force but with one problem there exists a key that converts the cyphertext into every possible plaintext of the same length and quantum random sources make all equally likely.

Comment: Symmetric Key encryption is not safe either.  It is only safe if used on messages smaller than the key, and never reusing the key.  If you try to encrypt a longer message (like using AES to encrypt something larger than 128 bits), your oracle can generate the 2^128 possible messages and do staticical analysis on those.  Any sort of structure in the data will quickly lead them to reject all except the correct key.  Thus, the only data that is safe is a string of random digits... which doesn't really need encryption int he first place!

Comment: Ammusingly, that makes Grammarly a weaponizable program!

Comment: Appeal to ephemerals?

Comment: I know you're looking for public key encryption, but just wanted to mention that there's a method using a pre-shared key that would work. It's called a one-time-pad and was used in WW2. It's unbreakable but requires a private key is shared on a secure line beforehand. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad

Comment: there's a book called: "A Fire Upon the Deep" by Vernor Vinge where everyone in the galaxy uses one-time pad encryption (I think... they just call it "pad" also they use it for signing which isn't possible). Might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 11):

If this omniscient being is capable of infinite computing power, then public key encryption will fail.

> all public key schemes are susceptible to a "brute-force key search
>   attack"

[Public-key cryptography: Weaknesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#Weaknesses)

Answer (score 5):

A computer with such an oracle can solve NP-complete problems in polynomial time.  Decryption is NP-complete, since you can verify a proposed solution in polynomial time.  Therefore, with the oracle, you can break any normal encryption (not just public key) efficiently.

For better visualization, picture you bringing your laptop to Delphi.  You ask the oracle what the key is.  She deeply inhales the gasses and then rattles of a string of hex digits.  You can plug that in and verify it easily, and get the output.  Since you can verify whether the key is the right one or not (the chance that a cipher block can decipher into two reasonable plaintexts is almost zero), that allows the oracle to be a little bit infallible.

This will not work for a one-time pad, since a ciphertext can be decrypted into literally any plaintext you like, so you can't verify that it's the correct answer.  You might as well just ask the oracle what the message says.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Computers are algorithmic engines, pure and simple. They can't perform non-algorithmic operations. There are some input vectors (like hardware random number generators) that are capable of introducing randomness as an *input*, but not randomness as a *process*, and even that doesn't help with encryption.

Ultimately, encryption has to be deterministic, because if it isn't, then you can't decrypt. What encryption does is create a complicated set of steps to obfuscate a message in some form, usually based on a key of some type. The idea is that you give the key to the intended recipient, and they reverse the process you used to obfuscate the process. Without the key, the obvious attack vector is guessing the key, or in other words a brute-force attack. All modern encryption methods try to make that as hard as possible, but the only way to make it *im*possible is to make it so the intended recipient can't open the message either.

Put simply, if someone can read the message with the key, then someone with an infinite supply of computational power can read the message with*out* the key. It's just a question of how badly they want the information. As such, encryption is about adjusting the effort/reward ratio to a point where for most people, it's just not worth the effort.

Comment: While true that computers are deterministic, I can still take a very simple (not even Turing complete) computer, the Enigma Machine, and produce encrypted text that you can not decrypt even with all of the resources of modern computers... despite Enigma Machines being a thoroughly "broken" encryption scheme. I simply have to have a key that is as long as the plaintext, and never use it for any other purpose.  If the cyphertext is "crf", then without the key, do you know if the plaintext is "foo" or "bar"?

Comment: That is -- This question isn't about encryption in general, but is looking for a specific family of encryption and asking if any member of that family has certain properties...  I.e., "Can mammals lay eggs" usually gets met with "no."  But "Can semi-aquatic, duck billed mammals lay eggs" gets met with a yes.

Comment: @Ghedipunk Semi-aquatic, duck billed 'mammals' are not really mammals; they're monotremes. (common mistake) So the answer is still no. The comment you make about non-Turing complete machines isn't about encryption, it's about ciphers, and having hidden, agreed meanings for specific phrases or even letters is a cipher, not an encryption. The Question *IS* about encryption generally, the title even asks specifically about public key encryption. Also, while I acknowledge your point in regards to foo and bar, messages of any size are easily cross-referencable for word sequences that make sense.

Comment: @Ghedipunk That would be called a One Time Pad I believe. The most secure form of encryption and also the one that relies on humans the most. The issue with a one time pad is the decryption stage. If I send a message encrypted by someone with a One Time Pad, I still need to send the One Time Pad which is just as vulnerable now. I can't encrypt a One Time Pad with another One Time Pad, since I need to send the new One Time Pad again. They simply shift the encryption problem to the Key which now needs to be securely transferred which is usually a bigger risk.

Comment: I get the need for being pedantic and precise... but... using a cipher and having hidden, agreed meanings for specific units of information to hide it from eavesdropping is encryption in all definitions of the word. Just putting it in a hidden form, regardless if how you do it, is encryption. And yes, the One Time Pad is most definitely NOT an example of private key cryptography, but it IS an example of something that fits within this answer: An algorithm that uses deterministic values to produce encrypted messages.  The first word of this answer is correct. The rest of it is [continued...]

Comment: The rest of the answer is like being asked about how film cameras get processed, and instead of talking about chemistry, etc., the answer talks about lenses and focus, which is a concept that applies equally to digital cameras as to film cameras, and doesn't address the details that are specific only to film photography.

Comment: @Ghedipunk "Can *any form of Public Key Encryption*..." What part of that question isn't precise, and what part of a Cipher constitutes Public Key Encryption? Call me a pedant if you must, but YES, I have answered the question in the OP correctly and film processing techniques aside, I'm struggling to figure out what your objection to my answer is. Hidden meanings in specific words, and small enigma ciphers just don't fall within the bounds of Public Key Encryption. If you can clarify your objection (and it's valid), I'm happy to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: The question is precise. However, your answer talks about the capabilities of the computer in general, not the details of private key cryptography.  That is why I bring up simple ciphers, because, simple ciphers are a form of cryptography that isn't private key cryptography... but your answer applies equally well to simple ciphers on very basic computing machines as it does to private key cryptography.

Comment: @Ghedipunk that sounds like you're saying it's a *good* answer...

Comment: Err... No. I'm saying it's answering the wrong thing.  This answer talks about computers in general, encryption in general, and never once goes into any details about the very specific sub-field of cryptography that is public key cryptography. I gave a counter-example of a stream cipher, an example of symmetric key cryptography, which can be implemented perfectly if the key is kept secret, and which fits in everything but the first word of your answer.

Comment: @Ghedipunk at this point I'm taking the downvote and just moving on. I appreciate the feedback, but I understand less about your objection now than I did at the beginning. At first I'm being too precise and pedantic, now I'm not being precise enough. Thanks for the effort, it does make the site a better place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86419/discussion-between-ghedipunk-and-tim-b-ii).

Answer (score 0):

No; by definition, the public key can be generated from the private key and vice versa, with the security depending entirely on **how hard** it is to do the latter compared to the former.  If all problems are equally hard, this can't be true.

It's always possible to encrypt an arbitrary message with the public key, and then use brute force  to find a key that decrypts your message correctly.  If there is a one-to-one correspondence between public and private keys, you're already done.  But perhaps there is some algorithm where a public key corresponds to a very large number of private keys for any given message; in that case, you still don't know which is the "universal" private key.  But you can just repeat the procedure with different plaintexts until there is only one candidate left, and again, your machine can by definition do this in no time.